# How can I plot price differences if I have list and my function is counting difference of every two elements and it drown nothingng

Tags: python, data-visualization, data-analysis

```py
price=[[3117.02002, 3105.459961, 3135.659912, 3131.060059, 3128.810059, 3110.280029, 3137.389893, 3035.02002, 3143.73999, 3311.3701170000004, 3322.0, 3241.159912, 3048.409912, 3004.47998, 3036.149902, 3211.01001, 3162.780029, 3286.330078, 3207.040039, 3204.399902, 3176.399902, 3184.939941, 3217.01001, 3207.209961, 3272.709961, 3338.649902, 3363.709961, 3443.6298829999996, 3442.929932, 3286.649902, 3190.550049, 3195.689941, 3099.959961, 3199.199951, 3125.0, 3221.26001, 3148.72998, 3144.8798829999996, 3174.050049, 3095.1298829999996, 3019.790039, 2999.860107, 3128.98999, 2960.469971, 2954.909912, 3008.72998, 3078.100098]]

def f(a):
    for i in range(len(a):
        print(a[i]-a[i-1])
```

Comment: Hi, can you make your question a bit clearer? I looks like your function already calcuates what you want it to. So what exactly would be your desired output?

Comment: Ah I see the problem, it is probably, because you start with 0 in your range. What if you replace `range(len(a))` by `range(1, len(a))`? would that print the result you wanted?

Comment: there is typo in `range(len(a)` (missing parethesis) and the problem in your approach is as mentioned, you start with incorrect index, your code does not draw anything because you don't even call the function

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list with this code.

```
    dif_list = []
def dif(price,dif_list):
    i = price[0]
    for j in price[1:]:
        diff = j-i 
        dif_list.append(diff)
        i = j

    return dif_list

dif_list = dif(price,dif_list)
```

And you can use pandas dataframes and matplotlib.pyplot to draw your data.
I couldn't see any effort for the problem so please try and draw.

Answer (score 0):

It'd be pretty straight forward using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(price, columns=['price'])
df.diff(periods=1).plot()
```

[image]